# Howto update multiple checkbox values at once on a array variable using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JQuery.
My question is: how can I update the value of multiple `CheckBox`es in an array variable?

I tested it and while clicking on every `CheckBox` it updated the checked `CheckBox` value and removed the unchecked `CheckBox` value from the array at each click. So far, so good.

But in my scenario I have more than 5 `CheckBox`es and if I click any checkbox I want to check all the other `CheckBox`es and update their values in the array variable.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: U know u can check multiple checkboxes at a time. So what happen if I check more than 2 checkboxes ?

Comment: I did a major reformulation of the question and incorporated a comment for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can create 2 array: `checked` and `unchecked` to deal with this

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  var checked = [];
  var unchecked = [];
     $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function() {
           checked[checked.length] = this.value;            
        });
        $("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").each(function() {
           unchecked[unchecked.length] = this.value;            
        });
        console.log(checked);
 });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" />1
<input type="checkbox" value="2" />2
<input type="checkbox" value="3" />3
<input type="checkbox" value="4" />4
<input type="checkbox" value="5" />5

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this  checkbox inside foreach loop which  has same name but dynamic Id. it will populate multiple checkboxes in dom.

```
 <input class="btn  btn-primary" id="Supplementarylesson_@objectlesson.LessonId" name="Supplementarylesson" value="@objectlesson.LessonId" type="checkbox")>
                                                                <label for="checkboxIsSmartSyllabus">
                                                                    Mark Supplementary
                                                                </label>
```

Get value of multiple checkboxes and store into array ,If checkbox is checked the we will store the value as true else false in array

```
$("#btnSupplementaryLesson").click(function () {

        var SupplementaryLesson = [];
        $.each($("input[name='Supplementarylesson']"), function () {
            SupplementaryLesson.push({ id: $(this).val(), value: $(this).is(':checked')?true:false });
        });

        SupplementaryLesson = JSON.stringify({ 'SupplementaryLesson': SupplementaryLesson });
        BlockUI();
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/LessonPlan/UpdateSupplementaryLesson',
        data: SupplementaryLesson,
        success: function () {
            UnBlockUI();
            showMessage("Lessons have been marked successfully.", "success");
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            UnBlockUI();
            showMessage("There is an error in saving supplementary content. Please contact system administrator.", "danger");
           
        }
    }); 

    })
```

On the Controller end, Action method has a list of

```
 public JsonResult UpdateSupplementaryLesson(List<SupplementaryLesson> SupplementaryLesson)
        {
            LessonPlanFacade ObjectLessonPlanFacade = new LessonPlanFacade();
             bool result=  
        ObjectLessonPlanFacade.UpdateSupplementaryLesson(SupplementaryLesson);
            if (result)
                return Json(new { status = true });
                return Json(new { status = false });
        
        }
```